# Implementing long press on tab bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tabbar, tabview, onlongclicklistener

I am new to flutter. I want to implement long press event on tab bar.
can somebody help me with this ?
A general idea of how to implement long press event on tabs of the tab bar.

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'GestureDetector' widget with 'onLongPress' property.

More information: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/onLongPress.html